# Extending or increasing volume of a quiet doorbell

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I have an old analog doorbell - there is a button for my apartment outside, and two wires come to where the chime is. When someone presses the button, a solenoid pulls back a little metal thingy with a piece of rubber at the end, and then releases it and it springs back and hits the chime. But the chime isn't very loud so it can only be heard in part of the apartment.

In order to remedy this, I decided to purchase a [doorbell extender](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Wireless-Door-Bell-Extender-Kit-HB-7902-02/206135540). Unfortunately, the existing chime is not loud enough to trigger the microphone on the doorbell extender, even on its most sensitive setting.

I'm looking for one or more of:

- a product that I can wire directly to the existing doorbell situation and cause something across the apartment to go off
- recommendations on how to make my existing analog chime louder
- recommendations for a replacement product for the analog chime, that will be loud enough to be heard across the apartment or at least loud enough to trigger the extender
- or something else that will solve my problem

Comment: Unfortunately, product recommendation requests are considered off-topic here. However, I can tell you that there are doorbell extenders that connect to the wires, instead of using a mic, for example, https://www.amazon.com/Safety-Technology-International-STI-3300-Hardwired/dp/B019EDQH2I . I use a similar (but older) unit in my 2-story house.

Comment: I don't feel like this is a product recommendation question - in terms of product recommendation I was just asking whether such a product existed. @ecnerwal's answer shows that this is a real question.

Answer (score 1):

Many "old analog doorbells" have some old-fashioned mechanical adjustments to alter the volume. If labelled at all, would commonly be something cryptic like a **+** at one end of a slot, or near a lever, or on the more verbose, a **+** at one end and a **-** at the other.

This might allow a longer distance for the striker to move so it hits harder, for instance.

You may also get results from changing or replacing rubber parts, or looking for things like a collection of dust or cobwebs (or eroded rubber parts) damping the chime itself.

Answer (score 1):

Save your money buy a new door bell. Can even get a app. and your phone rings.